# Get the eventual url for a file uploaded to S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Working on an app for a client that will asynchronously receive a request, reply immediately, then go out and fetch a set of large files to perform work on, and finally upload the results to S3 minutes or hours later.

Can we know ahead of time what the eventual url of the file on S3 will be? I'm thinking of creating a hash based on the filename and some other metadata that we know at the incoming request initialization and using that as the name of the S3 file. Is there a predictable pattern of S3 host plus bucket plus file name, or is it something that we don't know until the file upload is complete?

I'm entertaining the idea of returning the eventual S3 filename to the initial request, with the expectation that on the client's end they can periodically check the url for the result. In addition, I'm considering requiring the client to pass a callback url in with the request. The app will then hit that url later with the success/fail status of the work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL of a file uploaded to S3 can be entirely determined by you - it's purely dependent on the bucket and key name. Specifically, it's of the form:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/KEYNAME
```

(Or certain other formats, depending. It's still completely predictable.)

So long as you pick the key name ahead of time, you'll know what the eventual URL will be.